# How can I use two beans (or more) that return String in main program and replace them with another two while testing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class UrlAnalyzerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("usersDatabase")
    public File getUsersDatabaseFile() {
        return Paths.get("src/main/resources/database/users.csv").toFile();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("urlsDatabase")
    public File getUrlsDatabaseFile() {
        return Paths.get("src/main/resources/database/urls.csv").toFile();
    }
}
```

And configuration for tests:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("usersDatabase")
    public File getUsersDatabaseTestFile() {
        return Paths.get("src/test/resources/database/users.csv").toFile();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("urlsDatabase")
    public File getUrlsDatabaseTestFile() {
        return Paths.get("src/test/resources/database/urls.csv").toFile();
    }
}
```

---

My repository uses one of that beans:

```
    private final File usersDatabase;
    
    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryImpl(@Qualifier("usersDatabase") File usersDatabase) {
        this.usersDatabase = usersDatabase;
    }
```

---

My repostitory tests file:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestConfig.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    // tests here
}
```

At the result my main program works properly, but tests fail with followi message in the end:

*Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.io.File' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: getUsersDatabaseTestFile,getUsersDatabaseFile*

---

I have found the problem:

> @TestConfiguration class is used in addition to your application’s
> primary configuration.
> It means, that tests use @Configuration and @TestConfiguration together! But anyway, how can I use then my beans properly ?

Comment: Don't use `File`; it's not available at runtime. In general, use the Spring `Resource` instead.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- can you please then provide the correct code instead of mine or exaplain more precisely how to implement your idea?

Comment: Is there any other place you defined the test configurations? Looks like your test is also reading the `UrlAnalyzerConfiguration` file.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay no, I also thought about this, but no any other place

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-I have tried to use `Resource`, but the same error occurred

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay I have edited the question (I found out why this not work) and you were right: test was also reading UrlAnalyzerConfiguration, but can you then help, how to reimplement my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `@Profile` and `@ActiveProfiles` to load only the desired classes for your tests. See prototype below.

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestOnlyConfigs {
    // define beans
}
```

**Test**

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class Tests {
    // write tests
}
```

**References**

1. [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)
2. [@ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html)